# When passwords of a website leak, are all leaked passwords equally easy to read?

Tags: passwords, password-cracking

As far as I know, when passwords from a website leak, they leak in an encrypted form. Are all those passwords equally easy to decrypt? My hunch is that a 10-character-long password maybe gets decrypted in a few minutes, but if a password is 100-characters-long, it takes days or years to decrypt. Does it make sense?

Is setting a very long or difficult password a real protection from leaks? I'm asking even about passwords like `passpasspasspass11111passpasspasspasspass` compared to `pass11111`.

Comment: If the passwords are encrypted then you only need to brute-force the encryption key and then every password will be revealed. If they are hashed then you can build a rainbow table of known hash-to-password translations and just have to match the hashes to know the password. If your rainbow table does not contain a specific hash then you have to wait until your rainbow table grows. If the passwords are hashed and salted then the attacker probably won't waste their time. If it's plaintext then no obstacles should be encountered.

Comment: Not really an answer but since I don't see anyone addressing it: "passpasspasspass11111passpasspasspasspass" may be long but it's *still* a pretty bad password because of the repetition. A password half as long but actually random would be *much* safer.

Comment: @MichaelBorgwardt passpasspass...'s weakness depends on the bruteforcing algorithm ... Unless the hacker has a reason to limit themselves to just a character set of "aps1" it's reasonable to assume they'd be searching a-zA-Z0-9 in which case the extra length IS helpful.

Comment: @aslum But `pass` is a _very_ common word for passwords. The only surprising part is `11111`, but… Let's say you don't know which digit it is, the repetition could be anywhere from 2 to 10 and it could be in between any instance of `pass`, and that there are up to 20 of those. That's 10 × 9 × (1×2 + 2×3 + 3×4 + … + 20×21) possibilities: less than 50 000 to try, or equivalent to a 3-character random printable ASCII password. (And there aren't going to be up to 20.)

Comment: @wizzwizz4 For sure. If they're bruteforcing though, length is king. The real issue is if one of your other passwords is leaked in plaintext and you use a similar scheme. If they know you always use some quantity of "pass" plus some numbers it becomes trivial to bruteforce.

Comment: To Aslum and WizzWizz, in a way you're both right. Length does add significantly to the security of a password, even bad ones like that one with all the "pass." However, it's common for brute force algorithms to start with known patterns, such as "try all password combinations that are made up of letters from the set [pasword] and numbers" because that will crack a ton of lazy passwords, then they go on to more complicated ones. Still though, it should buy you some time to hear about the breach and change yours if yours is 41 characters because the hacker may likely go after short ones first.

Comment: You can have a long, secure password, but if it's stored in plaintext it might as well be the same as the combo for your luggage. Unfortunately you rarely know how "random internet site" stores your password until they have a breach.

Comment: @aslum: "bruetforcing" doesn't really mean trying all of [a-zA-Z0-9]+ strictly in increasing length, nowadays. Password cracking programs have gotten much, much smarter and will instead combine dictionary attacks with brute force in various patterns. People like repetition because it's easier to remember, and that is factored in. So it's quite likely that a pattern like "dictionary word repeated 2-10 times with a digit repeated 1-6 times somewhere in between could be tried, and then that would defeat this password within seconds.

Comment: @MichaelBorgwardt each "word" is still effectively a character. If you look at Repeating numberupto6x(60) and pass as the entirety of the entity space, that's still 61^10 (aka ~713,000,000,000,000,000) possibilities, which isn't going to be solved in seconds, and at that point you pretty much already have it solved.

Comment: @aslum: I'm not sure what you're calculating. 9 possibilities for amount of word repetition. up to 8 poss. for location of digits. 6 poss. for number of digits. 10 poss. for which digit. About 170k poss. for which dictionary word, realistically much less if you sort by commonality. I get 734 million in total. About as much as a truly random FIVE CHARACTER password. At best. Very small fraction of a second for SHA-256 on Bitcoin Mining hardware. Probably even weak using bcrypt, due to the very short and common word being used.

Comment: I was assuming that the possible character space was pass,1,11,111,1111,11111,111111,2,22,etc (so 61 total different entities). If instead the entities are pass and 0-9 then it's instead only 11 entities, but it's 15 long. Admittedly 11^15 is only e15 instead of e17 but that's still not trivial to brute force. I'm assuming the first example (passpasspasspass11111passpasspasspasspass) here. Assuming 80 entities, and a 5 character password, that's only 3billion possibilities, still a lot less to check.

Answer (score 52):

As others have mentioned, "*most sites*" hash the passwords, they do not encrypt them. But a site can choose to do whatever they want. Some sites have encrypted passwords and some have stored the password as plaintext. Obviously, if they are stored as plaintext, then there is no difference in how long your password is.

But let's assume that the site did what they are supposed to do and hashed the password with a salt. The length of the password does make a difference to the ability to brute force a guess of what the hash might be, but that assumes that the password is random.

***A hash of a 100-characters-long password that is well-known will be cracked very quickly.*** And that's a factor that a lot of people forget to account for. Length makes it more difficult to guess if you are having to guess each character at a time. ***But if you are using a dictionary of well-known passwords***, then length is no longer a protection if your password is in that dictionary.

So, your question is a good one. Not all passwords can be cracked as easily as others, and length can be a factor in how difficult it is to crack, but the overall factor to consider is ***how guessable the password is***. Length can make it harder to guess, but not by itself.

Comment: +1. [`correcthorsebatterystaple`](https://xkcd.com/936/) & [`ji32k7au4a83`](https://gizmodo.com/why-ji32k7au4a83-is-a-remarkably-common-password-1833045282) are good examples of passwords that seem long but aren't strong in practice, because they are commonly known.

Comment: "Strong Passwords" that LOOKS strong to a human are trivial to a computer. The computer has no understanding of meaning. Something like "ThisIsTheGreatestSongInTheWorldByJackBlack" is much stronger than anything random with symbols because most of you have it already memorized (excellent recall; no longer need to write it down) but it is just massively difficult to brute force. Symbols do NOT trip up a computer, so I have no idea why it is enforced to people, and forces them to write it down (extremely insecure).

Comment: @Nelson we have several answers here that explain all that.

Comment: @EsaJokinen Why do you call ji32k... a commonly known password? What makes it a bad password?

Comment: @musialmi They are linked and can be clicked on, and the articles clearly explain that.

Comment: @musialmi  ji32k... should be an *excellent* password, since going through all letters and numbers - perhaps with increasingly longer password-length - it will take a *long* time until you reach that password.  *However* since the password at some time has been *published*, it's likely that it's already been hashed and placed in lists of other pre-hashed passwords (eg. from dictionaries).  Since at least some readers are likely to copy and use such a "great password" from a book, it's worth the effort to crack... like *any other published example password* .

Comment: @musialmi &tldr; Basically, it translates to "mypassword" in Mandarin.

Comment: It should be noted that in a hash-based password system, it is not necessarily the original password that must be guessed. Any string that has the same hash will do if the input system will accept it.  Such a string does not need to be the same length as the one from which the hash was originally generated, so the benefit from increasing length falls off rapidly past some point.

Comment: @BaardKopperud For English attackers, yes, especially if they have never heard of this typing system. But for attackers whose main language is Mandarin, maybe not...

Comment: @JohnBollinger that's only true for the system for which the passwords were leaked. A different system will use a different salt, and I believe that causes the hash collisions to be different. Also, one of the reasons why attackers want to determine the plaintext is so that they can try the password elsewhere, so if they actually have a hash collision instead of the real password it won't work when they try to use it other places.

Comment: I think I'm missing your point, @RobWatts.  Supposing that we accept, *arguendo*, that a given hash algorithm in use for password hashing produces different collisions with different salts.  How does that conflict with my earlier remarks?

Comment: @JohnBollinger I suppose my comment was a bit of a tangent here, as this question isn't about password reuse. With a password that has more entropy than the hash output entropy, making it longer gives you some additional protection related to reuse instead of protection against someone brute-forcing your password. So the benefit does fall off rapidly, but because password reuse is a significant issue it's worth bringing up.

Answer (score 11):

> As far as I know, when passwords from a website leak, they leak in an encrypted form.

First of all, in general, passwords are not encrypted, they are hashed with good password hashing algorithms (like PBKDF2, SCrypt, Argon2) using a random salt per password. The password hashing algorithms are candidates for one-way functions, so there are no inverses of them as the encryption algorithms in which the decryption is the inverse of the encryption with the help of the key. The usual attack on those password hashing algorithms is searching for some space and testing for a known password set; [John the Ripper](https://www.openwall.com/john/) and [Hashcat](https://hashcat.net/hashcat/) are some of the tools that one can use.

Some sites like [Facebook stored the password in a clean format](https://www.theguardian.com/technology/2019/mar/21/facebook-admits-passwords-unprotected). When hacked, the hackers get all easily. If the passwords are well protected then the attacker needs to apply the search.

> Are all those passwords the same easy to decrypt? My hunch is that a 10-characters-long password maybe gets decrypted in a few minutes, but if a password is 100-characters-long, it takes days or years to decrypt. Does it make sense?

Here, assuming that we are brute-forcing the hash of the password, in that case, the 10 characters ( including the case sensitive and alphanumeric ) have 5.954 [entropy per character](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Password_strength). This makes 59.54 entropy and this can be achievable with [supercomputers or with the collective power of bitcoin miners](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/63537/18298). Approximately, [they can reach](https://www.blockchain.com/en/charts/hash-rate?scale=1&timespan=all)

2<sup>67.9</sup> in a second, 2<sup>84</sup> in a hour, 2<sup>84.3</sup>, in a day, and 2<sup>92.8</sup> in a year. This can give us some insight into possible agencies that may have the same or more power.

One must keep in mind that, running SHA256d as the miners do is not the same as running for PBKDF2, SCrypt, and Argon2 those are memory-hard password hashing algorithms. The memory-hardness prevents massive parallelization on GPU, ASIC, and FPGAs. Since the nodes of mining are not exact, estimation is not easy, however, if we look at Summit's Titan SUper computer that uses Tesla V100 27,648, and Titan can calculate around 2<sup>47</sup> PBKDF2-HMAC-SHA256 hashes per year. That is a drop from 2<sup>74</sup>, according to [hashcat results](https://medium.com/@iraklis/running-hashcat-in-amazons-aws-new-16-gpu-p2-16xlarge-instance-9963f607164c).

100 characters make sense and not. Setting it to 100 makes 594.4 entropy that is far from the need. Less than 256 should be enough for all. The problem, however, humans cannot memorize that kind of stuff so researchers developed [dicewire](https://www.eff.org/dice) and Bip39 kind of password systems so that they can have good entropy and easy to memorize. A must-see is [XKCD/936](https://xkcd.com/936/).

> Is setting a very long or difficult password real protection from leaks? I'm asking even about passwords like passpasspasspass11111passpasspasspasspass with comparison to pass11111.

Once you have a password that has good entropy and has different for each site/application then you should be safe. The usual way is using a password manager to manage all passwords like the [key-pass](https://keepass.info/) and use a password with a good entropy to keep the passwords safe.

There is competition on password set that actually search that kind of pattern, too. Forget about them and use dicewire kind of passwords that you can measure the strength of your passwords very easily.

Comment: Could you elaborate on "the collective power of bitcoin miners"?

Comment: @RoyceWilliams Hope, I did as you wanted. Actually, the link contained information about the search space that can reach.

Comment: I'm familiar with the general specialized/dedicated hashing capability of cryptocurrency platforms. What I'm trying to determine is how that relates to password cracking, given that Bitcoin is almost exclusively mined on ASIC these days, and those ASICs cannot be repurposed for general password cracking.

Comment: @RoyceWilliams Made clarifications and gave estimation for Titan for PBKDF2-HMAC-SHA256 and comparison from SHA2d, thanks.

Comment: You said "there is no inverse like the encryption algorithm". Don't you mean "unlike"?

Comment: @MartijnHeemels the Encryption must be reversible so that we can decrypt with the help of the key. From the hash algorithms, we don't want this. Note that one can build an encryption algorithm from [CTR mode](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/85572/18298) this is due to de design of the CTR mode and still we can decrypt by using the same path.

Comment: @MartijnHeemels: There is a lot of ambiguity in English.  You have chosen to parse the sentence as `(no inverse) like (the encryption algorithm has)` when the writer meant `no ((inverse) like (the encryption algorithm has))`  Both of these have the same sequence of English words.

Comment: @BenVoigt I see. Is it better now?

Answer (score 4):

> “ Is setting a very long or difficult password a real protection from
> leaks?”

Password complexity (length, character use, lack of pattern) is meant to protect from brute force attacks, not from “leaks.”

If someone were to use a 256 character password hashed with MD5, there is a chance that it would fall to a brute force attack (repeated guessing) because of a collision (two or more values that create the same result). Potentially, your 256 characters would have a match to a guess that is only 8 characters long.

When those 8 characters were used to log in to the account, they would generate the same hash as your password of 256 characters, and so the system would think the login is valid.

If you used your same 256 character password at a website that used SHA1 for hashing, the 8 character password that was brute forced (above) would NOT work, because the 8 characters would NOT generate the same hash using a different algorithm (cause the collision being exploited).

Rainbow tables (lists of hashes with their decrypted hashes) used to be a concern. This is mitigated by systems using a local variable referred to as a salt. This makes it so that you can not use a rainbow table without knowing the additional local variable (salt).

Passwords should be complex (pass phrase). Passwords should be memorable. Passwords should not be reused. You should be able to recover passwords. You should not be able to do it with a five or six character answer to a preselected question. Why? Because it’s easier to guess the answer (brute force) to a question, than a password of proper length/complexity.

Most important though, any system you are using should require multi-factor authentication.

Answer (score 2):

> Is setting a very long or difficult password a real protection from
> leaks?

No. If passwords are kept hashed, then for authentication only hash of a provided password is used. Many passwords can produce the same hash. E.g. even 10-12 character password can give the same hash as 100-character password. That's why longer password does not necessary mean that brute-forcing.

To protect passwords from brute-forcing use *resource expensive* hashing algorithms like Argon2, Lyra2, scrypt and similar. If parameters are properly chosen, each password candidate will require relatively much CPU and RAM. Brute-forcing can be very expensive and can take much time.

Nevertheless, using these algorithms for hashing does not mean it is safe to use *any* simple passwords.

Example: Suppose you configured parameters so that a single hash takes 1 s and needs 1 GB RAM on an average PC. If you use 3-character password consisting of characters from a let say 64-character set, then the total number of passwords to test is 64^3 = 262144. If an attacker has a 8-core CPU of similar core power, then it will take 262144 / 8 = 32768 seconds = 9 hours. Thus, 3-character password would be easy to break.

What is the reasonable minimal length? To answer this question consider the risks. How much are your secrets worth? How much money needs to be paid to brute-force passwords of particular length with particular CPU and memory parameters? Then you will see that may be for your particular case even 8-character passwords can be sufficient.

Comment: *"Many passwords can produce the same hash. E.g. even 10-12 character password can give the same hash as 100-character password."* While such hash collisions are technically possible, the odds are astronomical assuming a decent hash algorithm.

Comment: @user10216038: This is not quite true. Just an example: If we randomly choose 2 integer numbers *A* and *B* from the range *[1, 1000]*, what is the probability that *A mod 100 = B mod 100*? It is *0.01*. If we pick *A* from the the same range *[1, 1000]* and *B* from the range *[1, 1000000000000000000]*, what is the probability that *A mod 100 = B mod 100*? It is *0.01*, **the same** as for the smaller range. For hashes it is a bit more complicated, but the idea is the same.

Comment: No, no it's not. See *kelalaka's* answer here: https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/64674/hash-collision-probabilities#64675

Comment: @user10216038: The formula of *kelalaka* shows that collision probability depends on the hash length only. This formula shows that the probability **does not depend on the password length**. This confirms my statement and shows that *your* statement is incorrect.

Comment: I didn't say that. I said hash collisions are astronomically unlikely, contrary to your statement that *"Many passwords can produce the same hash"* , implying that it's a common event.

Comment: @user10216038: OK, so I misunderstood your comment. Correct, the probability is low. Despite this, making password longer *does not reduce* it any more. And this was actually the question in the OP. Then I don't understand why you wrote it here, not as a separate answer, because you are actually answering the OP :)

Comment: @mentallurg that analogy is a bit off... 128 bits of information is equivalent to 16 bytes, or needs 20 ASCII characters... a closer analogy would be the probability of picking A from [1,1000] and B from [1, 1000000000000000] and asking the probability that they're the same mod 1000000. In that case, it's rather unlikely that any possible A could be equivalent to B. Finding a 10-12 character password that gives the same hash as a 100-character password would be worse odds than winning a typical lottery. Sure it's possible, but it's not something you'd really be able to plan for.

Comment: @Steve: 1) There is no analogy at all. There is no connection between password length I given in the answer and modulo 100 in the comment. The only goal is to show, that increasing the range does not change the probability of collisions. Your 128 bit is not relevant, neither OP nor my answer talk about 128 bit.

Comment: 2) Finding a 10-12 character password that gives the same hash as a 100-character has **exactly the same** complexity as "Finding a 10-12 character password that gives the same hash as another 10-12 character password".

Comment: 3) This complexity depends on the hash length. If the hash is 8 bits long, finding collisions is easy. If the hash is relatively long, e.g. 256 bits, the probability of collision is very small. But again, no matter how big or small the probability is, increasing password length **does not change** the probability.

Comment: Or basically that you cannot have more bits (counted as entropy) in your password than  in your hash. So for a 256 bit hash and 6 bits of entropy per character there is no need for more than 256/6=42 character passwords, as finding collisions is as likely as finding the right answer.

Comment: but if one has a 64 character password @HansOlsson then it's much more likely they find a collision than one's actual password. It makes no practical difference, the account is forfeit, but allows a little smugness that they (probably) didn't use your password

Comment: @JCRM The point was that using using more than 42 characters, that is 64 or 100 etc adds no actual protection. Below 42 the protection is increased by each character - since you are more likely to find the actual password than a collision.

Comment: I would hope "It makes no practical difference" indicated I was in agreement @HansOlsson

Comment: @mentallurg "Finding a 10-12 character password that gives the same hash as another 10-12 character password" always has at least one solution - the original password - there is a 100% certainty that exhaustively searching all 10-12 character passwords would find one. "Finding a 10-12 character password that gives the same hash as a 100-character" almost always has no solutions. You need about 20 ASCII characters to have a reasonable chance of getting a collision in a 128 bit hash function.

Comment: @Steve: 1) To simplify, assume a single character needs exactly 6 bits. A 100-character psw. takes 600 bits. Your hash function produces 128-bit values. For *every* hash there are 2^(600 - 128) = 2^472 passwords that produce this hash. This holds also for every 10-12 character password. 2) You say *almost always has no solutions*. Why do you state that? Please provide a formula that confirms that. The probability math can be not so intuitive as one may think, take the birthday paradox for example. There are 2^472 solutions for every hash. Why do you say *almost always has no solutions*?

Comment: @mentallurg based on your simplification, a 12 character password needs exactly 72 bits. If you hashed every possible 12 character password, you'd have 2^72 different hashes. If you hashed every possible password of all lengths using 128 bit hash function, you'd have 2^128 different hashes (and many collisions between these longer passwords). This doesn't need a formula - the pigeonhole principle is sufficient to show that with only 2^72 "collision with 12 character password" hashes, the vast vast majority are not.

Comment: @Steve: I agree that for 128-bit hash making passwords longer than 10-12 characters does make sense, namely until we get 2^128 passwords, which is 20-21 characters. Thus the statement should be "making passwords longer than 21 characters does not increase resistance against brute-forcing".